# Use django rest api for filtering usernames starting with

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is probably a noob doubt. I am using the django rest framework and a react native front end. I am performing a search for usernames. So I want to return usernames similar to the ones typed in such as if the user starts typing, Ji then it should return:

1. Jim
2. Jimmy ...

I am using the following to try and retreive the usernames but only when the full username is entered the data is returned.

```
class SearchForUsers(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserAndProfileSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
       uname = self.kwargs['username']
       queryset = User.objects.all()
       queryset = queryset.filter(username=uname)

    return queryset
```

What alternative to queryset.filter should be used to get usernames and details on the fly?

Comment: Your questions is inconsistent, in title you are asking for filter on "starting with" and in body you are asking for "similar". Which one do you actually want?

Comment: Its for starting with..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check if the username `contains` what the user types, preferably [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) so its case insensitive

```
queryset = queryset.filter(username__icontains=uname)
```

If you just need to find out if the user name starts with the text, then use `startswith` or [`istartswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith)

```
queryset = queryset.filter(username__istartswith=uname)
```

Comment: It actually works with the __startswith, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @blaziken105 you could suggest edit for Sayse's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [SearchFilter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#searchfilter).  Something like this:

```
class SearchForUsers(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserAndProfileSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('username')
```